# How to solve build failed with an expection

Tags: android, flutter

Anyone who can solve this problem in flutter.Kindly help me. Thanks

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\hello_everyone\android\app\build.gradle' line: 1
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> Could not find method Properties() for arguments [] on project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: please add your build.gradle file

Comment: Please add your sample code, that get error

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the app/build.gradle from

```
def localProperties = Properties()
```

to

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
```

It is the first line in app/build.gradle. This might solve your problem.